# Preventing discoverability in a RESTfully routed model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I have a model in my database whose 'show' action is open to viewing at URLs like:

```
mysite.com/project/12
mysite.com/project/14
```

The way my system is set up, there are a couple of defined methods through which these should be accessible:

- A custom route I've set up is accessible to any visitor (registered or unregistered) who has this route. As an example, this custom route might be `mysite.com/companyname/projectid`, which the company might pass out itself to certain people it wants to have access. Note that this custom route runs a separate controller action, which sets some internal analytics then redirects to the `show` action.
- Direct access when linked to by a registered user's home page.

I want to restrict the ability to start with `mysite.com/project/14` then simply change the IDs, thereby seeing any project. How can I do this?

### Clarification

My goal with this question is not just to obfuscate record IDs to make discovering *certain* records harder. Instead, I would like there to be only two allowable means of accessing `project/12`:

1. A user clicks on a link we provide on their home page (how can I ensure this link alone reaches project 12?)
2. A user or simple visitor is redirected here by another (specific) controller action.

Typing in `project/12` directly should not be possible. At the moment, I imagine the best way to do this would be for the two methods above to pass a code that gets picked up by the `project#show` action. I just don't know how to implement this and if there are potential drawbacks.

Comment: So as I undestand it you don't mind people accessing the page (so not so much about security) but you care that the only way they do so is through one of the other methods?

Comment: @Jakub - exactly. I basically don't want projects to be discoverable unless the user either has the URL for that custom method or unless it is in the links presented on the home page.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that using Jakub's randomized method plus Kevin/nzifnab's session would provide a strong barrier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you come up with - it is going to end up being security through obscurity due to this simple requirement:

> A user clicks on a link we provide on
>   their home page (how can I ensure this
>   link alone reaches project 12?)

What you can do, however, is make it difficult to just straight-up guess the correct URL for the project.

My thought would be to give every Project a unique 'token' - If you are not logged in as the owner of the project, then you must use the token to access it.

For instance, in your project model you could have this:

```
class Project
  before_create :set_public_token

  protected
    def set_public_token
      # Randomizes a 20-digit long hex code
      self.token = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(20)
    end
end
```

Then, in your project's show action you would need to have this:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    # Obviously you would changed signed_in? to whatever method
    # you have that verifies someone is logged in
    if !signed_in? || @project.owner_id != current_user.id
      raise "Unauthorized Access" if @project.token != params[:token]
    end
  end
end
```

Then the owner of the project can share the 'public' link of their project to people they want to have access to it, which would look something like this:

```
www.example.com/projects/14?token=3jks83kasdkt84h6cd86
```

Again, *anyone* with that url could access the project, and I don't think you will be able to sanely get away from that - but it makes it a lot more difficult to do so.

This is the same concept many password reset functions work.  Anyone with access to the password reset token could reset your password after you've requested a password.  But knowing what token to use will take you ages (Make the token longer to make it harder to bruteforce).

That personally is how I would handle it, and how I've seen this sort of thing handled in the past (photobucket, private gists on github, etc)

Comment: @nzifnab - thank you very much for your detailed answer. Is there a convenient way of using a temporary hex key for each visit?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Do you want the token to 'expire' after it's visited, and require that the project owner has to give a unique url to each new person he shared his project with?

Comment: The project owner gives out the custom URL to a switchboard controller action, which then sends some users to this particular URL. The custom URL is static - I just don't want people to access this page directly without going through a controller that provides that single access key.

Comment: Are these other users who have been given access actual *users* in the database, or just some random person that project owner A sent an IM to for access to his project?  If they aren't registered users it might be more difficult to make the access single-use - because that implies that if they closed the browser and wanted to come back again, the same url they used last time wouldn't work anymore, and I'm not sure that would be desired functionality.  If you required them to register for an account after this single-use, you could then add them to some kind of ProjectShares model that would

Comment: give access until the owner revoked it

Comment: Yeah, that's the challenge - they're not always going to be registered users (they may or may not become users after visiting this page).

Comment: Well you could do this by making some kind of `ProjectToken` model that stores one-time-use tokens and `belongs_to :project`  (`Project has_many :project_tokens`) - after the url has been accessed for a specific ProjectToken it would redirect to the permanent tokenized project url (as designed in my original answer) and delete (or expire with a `used_at` timestamp) the ProjectToken entry.  Hopefully this is enough to get you started I think you should be able to take it away without me giving you specific implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to associate a project with a user or account, then require authentication when browsing your non public routes. If you setup an association, you can then do:

```
@user = current_user
@project = @user.projects.find(params[:id])
```

This will ensure that a given user can only find projects they 'own'.

If you don't want authorization, and just want obfuscation, you won't be able to use the 'id' alone in the route (as it is sequential). You could either pair the 'id' with a random key stored in the model (/projects/1?key=1234) or use a GUID instead of an id.

Answer (score 1):

OK so another attempt now that I sort of understand.

First in your public controller action you want to do something like this:

```
def public_redirect
  session[:authorized_for] = params[:id]
  redirect_to resource_show_path(params[:id])
end
```

Now in your private controller:

```
def show
  @resource = current_user.resources.find params[:id]
  if @resource # authorized
    respond_with @resource # ok
  elsif session[:authorized_for] == params[:id] #redirected from public route
    @resource = Resource.find params[:id]
    respond_with @resource # ok
  else
    raise NotAuthorizedException # not ok, do something
  end
end
```

This relies on sessions. This is certainly hackable, but it would be much harder then figuring out the public route. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions.

You can reuse the session technique for other similar needs (like for links from home pages where you can't verify the user from the controller, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that has a similar requirement. Now first I feel the need to say that this is security by obscurity - and thus not much security at all. But for some apps that can be OK.

I have a on create callback on my model that generates a random string (or number) that I use as my ID - thus it is <strike>impossible</strike> hard to guess another resource's path.

Comment: Hi Jakub. Obscurity is exactly what I'm trying to avoid here. My goal is to prevent the discoverability of ANY records outside the user's existing confines - as such, simply randomizing the IDs would not do a good enough job.

Comment: So what *are* you trying to do? Wouldn't simply restricting access work best?

Comment: Hi Jakub - I'm trying to restrict access to 1) users who enter through certain links we provide them on their home page, and 2) anyone (user or visitor) who enters through a separate controller action that redirects to this one.